# "Failed to instantiate one or more classes" after introducing FAB

Tags: xml, kotlin, build.gradle

I'm fairly new at making apps, I was following a guide for an instagram clone and after I introduced a floasting action button the "Failed to instantiate one or more classes" error appeared and now my app doesn't even work.

the following is the full error:

Exception Details:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:247)
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:212)
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:147)
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:76)
at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.(FloatingActionButton.java:212)
at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.(FloatingActionButton.java:201)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor5848.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:351)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:200)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:161)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:294)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:426)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:437)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:341)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:353)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:450)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:122)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:727)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$9(RenderTask.java:884)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:195)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$PriorityRunnable.run(RenderExecutor.kt:293)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Here are the relevant code pages

postfeed_activity.xml

`````
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recviewposts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabCreatePost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/floating_action"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:tint="#715B5B"
        app:backgroundTint="#7C4141"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>````

My build.gradle file id that helps

`
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    // Add the Google services Gradle plugin
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.relay' version '0.3.02' // Relay
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.dndgroupfinder'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dndgroupfinder"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.6'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.1'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.3.0'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
    // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.5.0')
    // TODO: Add the dependencies for Firebase products you want to use
    // When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    // Add the dependencies for any other desired Firebase products
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.1'
}`



I tried building the project and refreshing the layout as suggested but no luck.
`````

Answer (score 0):

For a similar problem the following solution worked for me -

In the res/values/themes.xml file change the name attribute of the style tag like changing
**Base.Theme.<your_project_name>** to **Theme.<your_project_name>**